# CDF of multiple experiment runs

Tags: python, cumulative-distribution-function

I have an experiment in which I run multiple times with different seeds (10 in this case).
As a result, I ended up with 10 different results.

I know that if I want to calculate the total mean, I calculate the mean of the means, since the results can be of different sizes.

Now, I'm not sure how to do that for the CDFs. What is the recommended way to calculate the CDF of these 10 runs? Do I use the entire result from my experiments and use to calculate one CDF?

In other words, how do I go about "merging" the three CDFs in this plot?

[image: CDF Plot]

The code that produce this graph is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A1':np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)})    
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A2':np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)})    
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A3':np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)})

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = sns.kdeplot(df1['A1'], cumulative=True)
ax = sns.kdeplot(df2['A2'], cumulative=True)
ax = sns.kdeplot(df3['A3'], cumulative=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Suppose I roll two six-sided dice 100 times, and record the results. I roll the dice another 100 times and record the results. Because the procedure is iid (by assumption), there's no meaningful distinction between the first 100 rolls and the second 100 rolls. I can concatenate these results and estimate a single empirical CDF using all 200 rolls. Is there a reason that this dice example is not similar to your problem? Because I don't think that you're really interested in random integers from a PRNG (or dice) but some actual analysis of real data, and subtlety would make all the difference.

Comment: @Sycorax I will concatenate my results and plot the ECDF, thanks for the explanation